# How to fix ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError for *ngFor with ion-input in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I currently have an ion-input that is going through a *ngFor so it repeats multiple times. When I want to add a new record (to add a new ion-input row) to the *ngFor loop, there is an error for:

**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: abc'. Current value: 'model: '.**

Here are my codes:

.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of values; let i = index;">
      <ion-input formControlName="taskDetail" [(ngModel)] = "values[i].answer" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="remove-circle" (click)="removeTaskOption(i)" slot="end"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

.ts

```
checklistCounter = [];
values = [];

constructor() {
    this.checklistCounter = Array(this.numCounter).fill(1).map((x, i) => i + 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.checklistCounter.length; i++) {
      let data = {
        id: i,
        answer:''
      }
      this.values.push(data);
    }
}


addNewTaskOption(){
  let data = {
    id: (this.values[this.values.length - 1].id + 1),
    answer:''
  }
 this.values.push(data);
}

removeTaskOption(i:number){
  this.values.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Here are some images for your reference:

Image of Original UI (Before clicking on add or remove ion-input rows):

[image: Image of Original UI (Before clicking on add or remove ion-input rows)]

Image of UI (After typing in 'abc' into the first ion-input then click on the add button:

[image: Image of UI (After typing in 'abc' into the first ion-input then click on the add button)]

Image of the error:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is even though the user has typed in something in the ion-input fields, if they want to add more fields, the fields will just appear below the original fields. I've read other solutions but all of them subscribe to a service and the solutions are for that, so I don't think I can apply it to my case. Please help!

**UPDATE: Managed to solve the problem by following @GaurangDhorda's answer.**

Codes:

.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of values; let i = index;">
      <ion-input formControlName="taskDetail" [value]="item.answer" (change)="setQuantity($event.target.value, i)" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="remove-circle" (click)="removeTaskOption(i)" slot="end"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

.ts (Added in new method)

```
setQuantity(ev:string, i:number){
     this.values[i].answer = ev;    
   }
```

Comment: Replace `[(ngModel)] = "values[i].answer"` with `[(ngModel)] = "item.answer"`

Comment: @Sergey The error is still there after changing it.

Comment: when does error occur? on load?

Comment: It's the same error like the one mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add thid piece of code to your compoent.ts file...


import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'component',
   templateUrl: 'component.html',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
 })

 constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){} 
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
 }
```

Comment: I have added these codes inside, now there is no error. However, when I type something (e.g. abc) in the first input field and I click on add, the data in that field (abc) disappears and now all the fields has been reset to blank.

Comment: okay.. that is another issue something with your code, but for error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` you have solved by my answer

Comment: Could you spot the error in my codes? I can't seem to spot it though.

Comment: UPDATE: I removed my ngModel and replaced it with value instead and it worked. But I still need the ngModel for my 2 way binding... Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: `<ion-input type="number" [value]="values[i].answer" (change)="setQuantity($event.target.value)"></ion-input>` here [value] sets value to input and (change) fires for every change event occurs in input. You have to define method setQuality() inside component and called by input change occurs.

Comment: Uhh I sort of get it. Could you provide me with the codes for the setQuantity method? Much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to solve it. I will update the codes in my question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Warning for others:**
The answer that is checked as "correct" is just a workaround for a wrong approach that initially mixed template driven forms (`ngModel`) with reactive forms. (`formControlName`) It should not be considered as the solution.

1) You either go with template driven form or reactive driven forms. Mixing them, does not provide a real value and can be considered as "code smell" and leads to errors as in your case.
When you want to have a two way binding I would suggest to use `[(ngModel)]` as you did in your first draft of your question. But then please remove the `formControlName=taskDetail`. (I would be wrong in any case to have the same `taskDetail` `formControlName` within the `*ngFor`)

2) With the solution you have now you are essentially doing two-way-binding manually yourself.

3) I have two examples that show your problem with [template driven forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-template-driven) and [reactive forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-reactive):

**Template Driven**
We need to have a distinct `name` attribute on your `input` when we use `ngModel`

```html
    <form>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of values; let i = index;">
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="item.answer" type="text" name="answer_{{i}}"></ion-input>
        <button (click)="removeTaskOption(i)">Remove</button>
      </ion-item>

      <button (click)="addNewTaskOption()">Add answer</button>
    </form>
```

**Reactive Forms**
Reactive forms come with a little more to write in the component class. There we setup a `FormArray` that holds the values:

```html
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">

      <div formArrayName="taskDetail">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of taskDetail.controls; let i = index;">
          <ion-input [formControlName]="i" type="text"></ion-input>
          <button (click)="removeTaskOption(i)">Remove</button>
        </ion-item>
      </div>

      <button (click)="addNewTaskOption()">Add answer</button>

    </form>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {

  myForm = new FormGroup({
    taskDetail: new FormArray([
      new FormControl('value 1'),
      new FormControl('value 2')
    ])
  });

  get taskDetail() {
    return this.myForm.get('taskDetail') as FormArray;
  }

  addNewTaskOption(){
    this.taskDetail.push(new FormControl('value NEWWW'));
  }

  removeTaskOption(i:number){
    this.taskDetail.removeAt(i);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following error does not come in prod mode.

Or

Add your values code in ngAfterViewInit() life cycle mode.

Comment: Sadly still doesn't work.. Thanks for your suggestion though